# Recursion with while loop check

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

The code below is meant to print out numbers in a range from 1 to a number from a user's input. But when a value `num` counts to the point where it equals to `endNum` - while-loop is supposed not to call the "numberToPrint" method again.

What is actually happening is that after `num` becomes equal to `endNum` and if-condition in the "numberToPrint" method goes as true, and continues towards `return`, it doesn't stop to implement the "numberToPrint" method here and right away switches to line 23, where actual recursion happens.

What can go wrong? Why doesn't it stop on `return` of true if-condition?

```
//recursive printing of numbers from 1 to a user's number

import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Type a number from 1 to 20: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer endNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        Integer num = 1;
        while (num!=endNum){
            numberToPrint(endNum, num);
        }
    }

    public static int numberToPrint(int endNum, int num) {
        if (num == endNum) {
            System.out.print(num + ", ");
            return num;
        } else {
            System.out.print(num + ", ");
            numberToPrint(endNum, (num + 1));
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop does not know about num value change, so you have an infitite loop here. This is due to local scope of num parameter. When you pass it to numberToPrint function, you are using a copy of it's value. And you never update num with returned value.

```
public class recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        Integer num = 1;
        while (num<= endNum){
            num = numberToPrint(endNum, num); // update num value
        }
    }

    public static int numberToPrint(int endNum, int num) {
         System.out.print(num + ", ");
        if (num >= endNum) {
            return num;
        } 
        return num + 1; 
    }
}
```

You are mixing here recursion and iteration. I would choose one of them, because here they are producing a large number of instructios.

With recursion this would look like this:

```
    Integer num = 1;
    numberToPrint(endNum, num);
}

public static int numberToPrint(int endNum, int num) {
    System.out.print(num + ", ");
    if (num >= endNum) {
        return num;
    } 
    return numberToPrint(endNum, (num + 1));
}
```